# I want to create a drop down list on my excel dashboard that filter the data based on my selection. How can i do that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, dashboard

Eg.

Drop down List: January to December

I want all my charts linked to this drop down list, which means when i click on February,my charts would only display Data of February

Comment: You could do this using [tag:vba]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of data you have, one way of doing this could be to make your data only show based on the month selected in the drop down list. To do this you create another blank sheet which will be an exact replica of your data sheet.

In each cell that will contain data you put the following equation in this case the equation is being input into `B1` where `A1` is the cell your drop down list is in and `'Data'!B1` is the cell your data is in on the original sheet, which for this case will be January data)

`=if(A1<>"January",NA(),'Data'!B1)`

Then you have your chart referencing the data of the replica sheet which will only graph the cells that have data in them (as charts ignore data with #N/A errors in them)

Hopefully this is clear but I'm sure there are many other more simple ways to achieve this.